# json.NET throwing an InvalidCastException deserializing a 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, casting, json.net

I'm attempting to deserialize a 2 dimensional array of `double` values from a json string.  The following code replicates my problem:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

// Here is the json string I'm deserializing:
string json = @"{
                    ""array2D"": [
                    [
                        1.2120107490162675, 
                        -0.05202334010360783, 
                        -0.9376574575207149
                    ], 
                    [
                        0.03548978958456018, 
                        1.322076093231865, 
                        -4.430964590987738
                    ], 
                    [
                        6.428633738739363e-05, 
                        -1.6407574756162617e-05, 
                        1.0
                    ]
                    ], 
                    ""y"": 180, 
                    ""x"": 94
                }";

// Here is how I deserialize the string:
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

int x = obj.Value<int>("x");
int y = obj.Value<int>("y");

// PROBLEM: InvalidCastException occurs at this line:
double[,] array = obj.Value<double[,]>("array2D");
```

The two integers, `x` and `y`, have the expected values `94` and `180`.  But when execution hits the `// PROBLEM` line, the following exception occurs:

```
An unhandled exception of type 
'System.InvalidCastException' 
occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: 
Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray
to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.
```

**How should I use json.NET so that this exception doesn't occur?**

The expected value of `array` should be clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
double[,] array = obj["array2D"].ToObject<double[,]>();
```

because, as per @dbc,

> the difference doesn't seem well documented. [JToken.Value](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs) basically does a [Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) which is for primitive types, while [ToObject()](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs) actually deserializes.

Comment: That does work.  Can a JSON.NET guru explain the difference?

Comment: @kdbanman - the difference doesn't seem well documented.  [`JToken.Value<T>`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs) basically does a [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) which is for primitive types, while [`ToObject()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs) actually deserializes.

Comment: Thanks @dbc, great sleuthing!

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
JObject j = JObject.Parse(json);
var list = j.SelectToken("array2D").ToString();
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double[,]>(list);
```

This line:

```
JObject j = JObject.Parse(json);
```

does not deserialize the data, it simply parses it to an `Object`. You still need to tell JSON.NET what type of object you want it serialized to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Just FYI: *"You still need to tell it what type of object"*  That's exactly what the type parameter to the generic method `.Value<double[,]>` is supposed to do.

Comment: `(double[,])j.SelectToken("array2D");` doesn't compile.  There's no explicit case from [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) to `double [,]`.  And `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double[,]>(list);` also doesn't compile because `list` is not a string or implicitly convertible to a string.

Comment: I was installing visual studio and couldn't test it. I forgot the ToString(). Try it again and it will work.